# Export existing android app as aar (like a library)

Tags: android, aar, android-security, android-module, android-flavors

***Background***: I have an android application that has been published in GooglePlay and I want to create SDK from that existing application so that others can use it as a library inside their apps.

***So far:*** I was able to generate .ARR file from the existing app source code with little tweaks. and it is working pretty good.

***The problem***: is I have some sensitive information stored inside my app
since I made .arr file from my app codebase I'm little worried that they can easily get access to my `SharedPreferenceManager` (util class of mine to deal with SharedPreference) `DataBaseManager` so on and they can subclass library class and tweak the behaviors

So How can I avoid library users not to misuse my library to exploit my existing app?
is there any other way to export my app as a library?

Answer (score 0):

The basic process would be as follows:

1. Figure out what you want to expose in your SDK
2. Move all of this into an `android library` module
3. Deploy the AAR

Can you explain a little more what you mean by "I'm little worried that they can easily get access to my SharedPreferenceManager (util class of mine to deal with SharedPreference) DataBaseManager so on and they can subclass library class and tweak the behaviors" ?

You can always utilize obfuscation techniques and finalize classes to make it difficult. I don't think you can guarantee absolutely no misuse, but I am not sure how this would effect your application. If you have a server, for instance, then you would still control the software there and be able to sanitize and sort through the input.

Comment: basically, the app is for operate a machine, there are some static variables in app which decides the core business logic, so they can tweak those variables

Comment: If they're static final variables, they'd really need to go out of their way to change them.

Comment: they aren't final just static